# UFW rules not working as expected

Tags: networking, firewall, raspbian, ufw

This is how the UFW configuration looks like in my Raspberry PI

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1194/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.8.0.0/24               
1194                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
53682                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8001/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24            
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
53682 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8001/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere on wlan0          ALLOW FWD   10.8.0.0/24 on tun0
```

The IP range 10.8.0.1 - 10.8.0.255 is the IP assigned to anyone connecting via VPN
The IP range 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255 is the IP assigned my home local network (where this device is also connected).

My understanding is that the `To Anywhere from 10.8.0.0/24` and `To Anywhere from 192.168.1.1/24` is more than enough. But it wasn't working as expected, hence the additional rules.

I am trying to figure out why the above rules aren't working and why do I have to specify the additional rules for it to work properly? Is my `To Anywhere from ...` rules defined wrongly?

I can confirm that things are working properly with the firewall turned off.

Comment: Confirm things are working with the firewall turned off because I think you have a routing issue.

Comment: I've already confirmed that things are working when firewall is turned off.